# Refactoring when a method has been moved into another (static) class

Tags: java, eclipse, refactoring

I had my clearScreen method in my Settings class and moved it into my Formats class. Since ive used it many times already i dont really want to change it every time. When I try to rename it using refactoring though, it gives me these errors: "Compilation untit Formats.java already exists" and "Type named Formats already exists in Package(default package)"

Is there any way to refactor the class thats being called?
If it isnt clear what i mean, it would go from

```
Settings.clearScreen();
```

to

```
Formats.clearScreen();
```

Comment: Have you tried a simple find/replace (ctrl+h)

Comment: @dfour this may work, provided you don't need to add any imports, the call isn't split over lines etc.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to:

1. Add the method in the new location
2. Change the existing method to call the new method:

   ```
   class Settings {
     // ...
     void clearScreen () {
       Formats.clearScreen();
     }
     // ...
   }
   ```
3. Select `clearScreen` in `Settings` and [inline it](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-menu-refactor.htm).